# JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'dialog'

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-5

I am getting that error while I call fuction `f1` from my AJAX helper in MVC 5.

```
$.fx.speeds._default = 2000;
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#d1").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        width: '800',
        height: 'auto',
        model: true,
        show: 'blind',
        hide: 'explode'
    });
});

function f1() {
    $("#d1").dialog("open");
}
```

My AJAX helper call:

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Delete", "DeletePartial", new { id = item.Id }, new AjaxOptions {
    UpdateTargetId ="d1",
    LoadingElementId="L1",
    InsertionMode=InsertionMode.Replace,
    HttpMethod="Get",
    OnComplete="f1"
})
```

I have properly mentioned AJAX reference and jQueryUI refrences, but it's still not working.

Comment: Is this `model: true` supposed to be `modal: true`?

Comment: edit your question and mention exact errors

Comment: I am using this in mvc 5 error is same

Comment: ...and you're certain that you've included the dependency to [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/)?

Comment: yes i am included the dependency to jQuery UI?